# Парсинг фото с сайта

Tags: бот, beautiful-soup, bs4, lxml

Подскажите пожалуйста,  как можно реализовать парсинг фото с сайта , для последующие отправки ботом. Пример html кода:

```
<a href="tortyi/listіvka" class="catalog-product__link-img">
                <img src="/assets/images/products/274/catalogthumb/lyst.jpg" alt="Листівка" title="Листівка" class="catalog-product__img">
        </a>
```

Благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Тебе нужно, чтобы оно скачивалось?

Comment: Ваш код предоставте для начала плодотворного сотрудничества. Обьязательно укажите чем собрались парисит. Че за бот? А то вечно все думают, что на этом ресурсе собрались одни настрадамусы.

Comment: Меню с товарам взятыми с сайта , текст и сылку я смог взять, а вот с фото проблемы.

Comment: В боте : при нажатие на кнопку "меню" присылаете ботом товары и фото их

Comment: Бот сам скачивает фото с сайта , т.к меню обновляется

Comment: 'вот с фото проблемы' и в чем проблема? Проблема в урезаной ссылке src="/assets/images/products/274/catalogthumb/lyst.jpg"?

Comment: Проблема:1.скачать все фото с сайта и 2.чтобы бот отправлял правильно фото с текстом